# Changing items after submit via an Event Receiver

Tags: event-receivers

I would like to set up an itemadding and itemupdating event receiver such that it automatically populates some values on submit and then gives the user the opportunity to change those values.

Example:
User fills out form (one field is a lookup field - Cost Center).
User submits form.
Based on the Cost Center, a person column named Approver is populated with data from another list.
The User is presented with the opportunity to change the Approver field.
If the Approver column is changed by the user, I would like to set a flag indicating the change.

I am mostly just asking if this is possible using the default newform and editform.  I don't want to go down a rabbit hole and lose a couple days if this can't work.

Comment: Do you have to do this with an event receiver? Couldn't you do this client side, eg populate the Approver automatically when you change Cost Center. Then users could change the Approver if they like

Comment: That works for me.  Sometimes I over think a solution.  Thanks!